# What is the significance of HashMap<String,Object>.toMap

Tags: java, android, android-studio, hashmap, loopback

I am developing an Android App and I am stuck with something. I am using Loopback as my backend framework, in which I have to pass a hashMap, but Android Studio is showing me error that I should convert it into `toMap`. Below is my piece of code, I have google but doesn't find the solution of `Why should we have to use toMap`.

```
HashMap<String,Object>vehicleInfoObj = new HashMap<>();

customerQuoteRepository.createCustomerQuote(ctx, vehicleInfo.toMap(), customerQuote.toMap(), new ObjectCallback<CustomerQuote>() {
        @Override
        public void onBefore() {
            super.onBefore();
            mainActivity.startProgressBar(mainActivity.progressBar);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CustomerQuote object) {
            super.onSuccess(object);

        }


        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            super.onError(t);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinally() {
            super.onFinally();
            mainActivity.startProgressBar(mainActivity.progressBar);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks! In other words --- your question is missing the exact error message, and a clear indication which line gives the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `toMap()` method in the Java Map API. But there is one in the `loopback-sdk` e.g. [here](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-sdk-android/api/com/strongloop/android/loopback/Model.html#toMap()). The signature of `createCustomerQuote` expects a `Map<String, ? extends Object>` - that's why you have to use `toMap()`.